# Does opting to received SMS in Google Hangout means no longer received by Google Voice?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-voice

Does opting to received SMS in Google Hangout means no longer received by Google Voice?

Can I receive SMS in both Hangout and Voice?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't

> If you turn on Google Voice text messages in Hangouts, they'll only be available in Hangouts and not in Google Voice. Only old text messages before you turned this feature on will be available in Google Voice.

From [Google Voice Help](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/6023920?p=voice_sms&rd=1)